# Look for a method of WorksheetFunction which returns an Integer

Tags: vba, types, excel, type-conversion

I consider `TypeName` function returns the exact type of a data in VBA. Now I am looking for a `WorksheetFunction` which can return an `Integer`, instead of `Double`.

A lot of `WorksheetFunction` returns `Double` in VBA, for example, `MsgBox TypeName(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 2))` gives `Double`. Oddly some functions which are supposed to return an `Integer` give also `Double`, for example, `MsgBox TypeName(Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A2:A10")))` and `MsgBox TypeName(Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(3))`.

So does anyone know if there is a `WorksheetFunction` which returns a `Double` and can let `TypeName` detect it?

Comment: Why does it matter? I doubt there are any, Double is the standard numeric return type; in the VB editor press F2, search for WorksheetFunction and you can see them all listed with their corresponding return type.

Comment: yep - stepped throught - only double, string and boolean as return values for worksheet-functions - interesting though

Comment: If you have a statement that combines several mathematical worksheet functions you don't really want a piddly 16bit integer popping up to introduce implicit conversions, rounding or overflows

Comment: I thoroughly agree with the posts above from @AlexK. If you really want an integer though, can't you just convert it with `CInt` -> of course, it will fail if the number is less than -32,000, greater than 32,000 (32,000 is rounding, I forget the exact number off top of my head)

Comment: Well `MsgBox TypeName(2 + 3)` returns `Integer`, that means VBA, `TypeName` and `+` operator recognize `Integer`, that also means methods of `WorksheetFunction` are not very fine in terms of types, at least not as fine as some other operators in VBA (`+`...). But, thanks for the info...

Comment: Undeclared/literal whole numbers default to being VBA Integers (a bad choice but legacy support dictates it to be so) and an integer+integer=integer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the int() function to retrieve the output of one of the functions you mentioned in Integer format.